# Получение загруженности каждого ядра

Tags: c#, железо, lib

Я смог получить общую загруженность процессора через Open Hardware Monitor Lib вот так:

```
public static short GetCPUUsage()
{
    Computer myComputer = new Computer();
    myComputer.CPUEnabled = true;
    myComputer.Open();
    foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
    {
        if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
        {
            foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
            {
                if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load)
                {
                    hardwareItem.Update();
                    return Convert.ToInt16(sensor.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Но как мне получить загруженность каждого ядра?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему так:

```
hardwareItem.Sensors[0].Value // Core #1
hardwareItem.Sensors[1].Value // Core #2
hardwareItem.Sensors[2].Value // Core #3
hardwareItem.Sensors[3].Value // Core #4
```

Имена можно получить так:

```
hardwareItem.Sensors[0].Name // Core #1
hardwareItem.Sensors[1].Name // Core #2
hardwareItem.Sensors[2].Name // Core #3
hardwareItem.Sensors[3].Name // Core #4
```

Чем вас ваш код кстати не устраивает, вы же вроде тоже самое и получаете?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]